# Solaris 11 can i run Android dalvik?

Tags: java, android, solaris, opensolaris

How to run Solaris 11 or Cloud Solaris 11, Android Java? Or i can use the same Solaris 11 java. This is the script i was trying which works in Solaris 11 but not in Android.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class HelloNonsenseDroid 
{
    private static String myInput = "no";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {  
      System.out.print("Q. Are you Xroid? Answer. ");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      myInput = br.readLine();

      if (myInput.equals("yes")) 
      {
        System.out.println("Yes! you are genius");
      } else {
        System.out.println("No! what in the earth, is No! try to learn to say \"Yes, we can\"");
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Go language. $ 5g main.go && 5l main.5; and copy paste 5.out works in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just run normal Java console apps on android. Android has it's own GUI system to show "windows" and other GUI elements. You need to use those to show content to users.

Start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: Where do Android Java stands? like we have JavaSE, JavaEE, JavaME. Android Java is Java{GoogleJavaTrollers}?

Comment: Android Java is not JavaSE, Google never claimed it is. The "script" runs on JavaSE. Sun created several versions of Java that are targeted at different environments: JavaSE, JavaEE, JavaME. BTW, your script does not run on JavaME, so don't complain (troll) that it does not run on Android.

Comment: Also, Java language is not JVM (java virtual machine). They are two distinct things (much like C# and .net CLR). Sun's marketing called everything "Java" so this is where confusion comes from.

Comment: Well you are very correct i know. Honestly speaking Google may called it "Google language" Such as D or Vala language which looks like C or C++ but it does not call himself C. But here Mr.Android called it straight Java. But truth is they claim Linux, Java for marketing troll in reality they are saying we are not Java or Linux once you buy the product and try to hammer it.